# Mapping vim tab to with key to automatically open NERDTree

Tags: vim, tabs

I have made a key mapping for Vim's tab functionality as

```
318 map <C-h> : tabprevious<CR>$
319 map <C-l> : tabnext<CR>$
320 map <C-t> : tabnew<CR> <Esc>:NERDTree<CR>$
```

but it does not seem to work . Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the leading numbers and trailing `$` are for.

Try these:

```
nnomap <C-h> :tabprevious<CR>
nnomap <C-l> :tabnext<CR>
nnomap <C-t> :tabnew<CR>:NERDTree<CR>
```

All characters in the mapping are treated literally (as if you typed them). Note that the `noremap` versions are safer because they are nonrecursive, although it makes no difference in this case. Also, `nnoremap` is restricted to normal mode, which makes sense for these mappings (you don't want to be insert mode while you are switching between tabs).

Comment: Thanks it worked :D .. I have installed some plugins(http://sontek.net/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide) which show line number in beginning and a '$' as EOL.